# Select receber valor personalizado no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu possuo um select no meu form:

```
<%= form.select :status, options_for_select([ ["Ativo", 0], ["Inativo", 1] ]), {include_blank: "Selecione ..."}, class: "form-control", required: true %>
```

Para incluir um novo registro, o meu código funciona, só que quando eu clico no botão para alterar o produto, o meu select, não recebe o valor do banco de dados.

Exemplo: Determinado produto, está com o valor = 1, logo, quando eu clicar no alterar, ele deveria estar com o valor = "Inativo".

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o selected como abaixo:

```rb
 <%= f.collection_select :cid_ids,
   @cids_to_select,
   :id, :descricao_select,
   {selected: @cids_in, include_blank: false},
   {required: true, class: 'select2', multiple: true}
 %>
```

No controller vc deve ter o Objeto referente a view instanciado.

Answer (score -1):

Deveria pegar automático mesmo do model que vc. está usando. Vocês está usando  [enum](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#enums) para essa coluna de status? Talvez seja isso.Para resolver o problema você pode adicionar a config `selected`

```rb
<%= form.select :status, 
      options_for_select(
        [ ["Ativo", 0], ["Inativo", 1] ],
        { selected: form.object.status }
      ), 
      {include_blank: "Selecione ..."}, 
      class: "form-control", 
      required: true %>
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Como seria usando "enum" para a minha coluna?

Comment: lendo novamente a pergunta, eu descobri porque não estava magicamente pegando do model. Você pode tirar o `options_for_select` e direto o array de array de status. Esse `options_for_select` não faz parte do objeto `form`, por isso acredito que não pegou automático. Consegue validar? Seria que nem está na [doc do rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease)